# My jquery counter is mixing the elements - why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a small html page with a table full of currency values.

```
   TEXT     |   SUM    |   LIMIT  |
-----------------------------------
Text One    |   1.700 €|   1.500 €|
Text Two    |   1.945 €|   2.000 €|
```

html:

```
<tr><td>Text One</td><td class="text-right text-nowrap"><label class="euro counter" target="1200" limit="1500"></label></td><td class="text-right text-nowrap"><label class="euro">1.500</label></td></tr>
<tr><td>Text Two</td><td class="text-right text-nowrap"><label class="euro counter" target="2345" limit="2000"></label></td><td class="text-right text-nowrap"><label class="euro">2.000</label></td></tr>
```

Then I added a jQuery counter which counts up to the target value.
This works fine. But I also want to add a condition, that the value gets colored red, if it is greater than the limit. but the counter mixes both values and the SUM is getting red after the first LIMIT 1.500 is reached.
How can I separate all the values on a generic way?
Here is the js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.counter').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        target = $this.attr('target');
        limit = $this.attr('limit');
    $({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
      countNum: target
    },
    {
      duration: target*2,
      easing:'swing',
      step: function() {
        if (parseInt($this.text(), 10) > limit) {
          console.log($this.text());
          $this.addClass('f-red');
        }
        $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Edit: In the table example - I only want to display the first SUM value in red but my actual counter code displays both SUM values in red because both are higher then the smallest limit (1.500). How can I have a separate limit for each line?

Comment: It is doing exactly what you ask. This: `$('.counter').each(` makes identical changes to _every_ element with a classname `counter`.

Comment: Yes but I asked: "How can I separate all the values on a generic way?" so I want that only the first SUM in the example gets red but this code makes both SUM entries red because the "overall limit" is 1,500. And I want the limit for each line.

Comment: As per this fiddle it seems to be working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/7thLzn41/

Comment: Hmm strange you code works, but if I now change the target of the first SUM - its not running properly yet :( -- http://jsfiddle.net/ohkqmj4c/#&togetherjs=LqVF22GFco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not working because you cant use a variable and expect it to have different values while synchronously using it.

to be exact its enough to change this line

```
if (parseInt($this.text(), 10) > limit) {
```

to

```
if (parseInt($this.text(), 10) > $this.attr('limit')) {
```

to always compare to the actual limit

http://jsfiddle.net/umdnq38t/

Comment: That‘s it! Thanks!

Comment: glad it worked, btw instead of calling text() each time you can just compare `(this.countNum > $this.attr('limit'))`